# How do I support social media sharing and previews of my SPA NuxtJS app

Tags: vue.js, seo, nuxt.js

I've been making a SPA NuxtJS app. I inserted the appropriate code for setting the required meta tags, then I tried sharing a link on LinkedIn, but it wouldn't provide a preview, saying that an error has occurred.

I tried checking the preview via LinkedIn's [tool](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect/), but it returns the 404 error. If I put the same URL into the browser, the page opens just fine.

Is it possible to enable social media previews for a statically served NuxtJS SPA, and is it possible to do it for dynamic routes as well? If yes, how?

UPDATE: I've managed to get a simple preview going using the [Nuxt SEO package](https://github.com/TiagoDanin/Nuxt-SEO). This, however, always displays the default image and title in the LinkedIn preview.

nuxt.config.js

```
modules: [
    ...,
    'nuxt-seo',
    ...
],
seo: {
    title: 'Default title',
    og: {
      image: <default image>
    }
},
```

async data in component:

```
asyncData: (ctx) => {
    ctx.seo({
      title: 'Custom title in component',
      og: {
        image: <link to alternate image>,
      },
    })
},
```

For dynamic pages, I've managed to avoid the 404 error by pointing requests to index.html so they can be found from there.

Comment: *I inserted the appropriate code for setting the required meta tags, then I tried sharing a link on LinkedIn, but it wouldn't provide a preview, saying that an error has occured.* -- you're more likely to get help if you can [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will attempt to do so as soon as possible.

Comment: Have you solved it? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Sadly, no. I'm using prerender.io as a temporary solution and I've also been looking at server-side rendering with AWS (so technically serverless-side rendering, but my app is too big ti be run in a lambda. If you are interested, there is a git repo called something like "serverless nuxt" that has a sample project.

Answer (score 1):

I am the new maintainer of the [nuxt seo package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nuxt-seo). There is a full example of how to setup and use [nuxt seo for a blog](https://nuxt-seo.frostbutter.com/examples/blog), including having social share images. That will explain more of what I am repeating here:

Nuxt SEO is certainly able to support both server side render (SSR) apps, and statically generated app.

I would add your "global default" settings in your `nuxt.config.js` file. Including a default social media image and social media handles.

```
export default {
  seo: {
    baseUrl: 'https://frostbutter.com',
    name: 'Site Name',
    templateTitle: '%name% — %title%',
    description: "Hi! I'm Nick, an indie developer.",
    keywords: 'indie, developer, nuxt',
    canonical: 'auto',
    isForcedTrailingSlash: false,
    author: 'Nick Frostbutter',
    openGraph.image: {
      url: 'https://frostbutter.com/img/nick.jpg',
    },
    twitter: { 
      site: '@nickfrosty', 
      creator: '@nickfrosty',
      card: 'summary',
    },
  }
}
```

Then for each of your individual pages you want to have custom social share images on, like the articles you are trying to share on linkedin, override the global defaults inside the `head()` for statically set values, or using `asyncData` for data that must be fetched from an api or other source, like nuxt content.

```
<template>
  <article>
    <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
    <img :src="post.image" :alt="post.title" />
    <nuxt-content :document="post" />
  </article>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    async asyncData({ params, error, $content }) {
      const [post] = await $content("blog", { deep: true })
        .where({ slug: params.slug })
        .fetch();
      return { post };
    },
    head({ $seo }) {
      $seo({
        title: this.post.title,
        description: this.post.description || 'fallback description',
        keywords: keywords,
        image: this.post.image || '',
        twitter.card: 'summary_large_image'
      });
    },
    computed: {
      keywords(){
        return this.post.keywords ? this.post.keywords : this.$seo.keywords;
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

PS: I have created a more comprehensive docs site for the nuxt seo project. I will look more into linkedin social media sharing rules and try to add some docs to the site for it.
If you have any good resources you have found, then let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your response! This issue is no longer applicable, as that part of the application is no longer in use. I would still like to thank you for your response and I hope that it helps people with similar issues in the future!